# Test the message returned by an akka actor containing a Try[T]

Tags: scala, try-catch, akka, akka-testkit

I am developing an Akka actor that respond with a message of type `PutAck[Try[String]]`. The problem is not how to develop the actor itself, but the unit tests.

Given that the following actor code

```
private def put(store: Map[String, Array[Byte]], key: String, value: Array[Byte]) = {
  try {
    val newStore = store + (Objects.requireNonNull(key) -> value)
    sender ! PutAck(Success(key))
    context.become(nonEmptyMap(newStore))
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception =>
      sender ! PutAck(Failure(ex))
  }
}
```

I wish to test it with the following test

```
"A Storekeeper actor" must {
  "receive an error message for a couple (null, value)" in {
    val sk = TestActorRef[Storekeeper]
    sk ! Put(null, SerializationUtils.serialize(42))
    expectMsg(PutAck(Failure(new NullPointerException())))
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the test fails with message

```
assertion failed: expected PutAck(Failure(java.lang.NullPointerException)), found PutAck(Failure(java.lang.NullPointerException))
```

I supposed that the failure is due to the different`hashCode` that the two exception have.

How can I test this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it does match is that instances of `NullPointerException`s are only equal to themselves, not other seemingly identical instances.

What you can do instead is to expect the message on type, catch the response as a value and then assert whatever you want about it, something like this:

```
val ack = expectMsgType[PutAck[Try[String]]]
ack.value.isFailure should === (true)
ack.value.failed.get shouldBe a[NullPointerException]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed this method in the API :)